# How to connect a load to an amplifier without a loss in gain?

Tags: transistors, amplifier, analog, load

I have this circuit below, that represents a common emitter amplifier:

[image]

When connecting a load of 10 ohms to the collector node and a signal to the base node there is a huge loss in the gain of the circuit. My question is how can i design a way to make the gain at least 3 with a load of 10 ohms.

Comment: This amplifier has an output resistance of 10k. In 10 ohms this will not do much.

Comment: You need to use another transistor stage to act as a buffer to the load.

Comment: With a load 100x lower in impedance than RE and 1000x lower than RC there would be. How were you expecting to get power to that load? If the load doesn't care about having DC across it, use the load as RC and design around that. Otherwise, do more research.